# Socket and Thread approach to send frames in C (win32)

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi, thread-safety, winsock

I'm creating a simple program to capture frames from USB devices (USBCap) to send it through network to my second program, the Image Server (IMGSvr).

Both programs will run in the same machine or in the same local network, ever.

The USBCap captures more than 1 USB device (named "channel"). To do this, I'm using a threaded procedure to each channel, which is getting new frames from DirectShow wrapper (videoInput).

The problem starts in the socket: It's using just one TCP SOCK_STREAM connection to send frames to IMGSvr. send() is blocking subsequent calls of send() (by other threads) util frame is sent.

So if it blocks all threads, why I'm using multi threaded program?

What's the best way to solve it? Maybe adapt the program to threads puts new frames in a frame's queue so another thread to empty this queue, sending queued frames to the IMGSvr.

What do you think?

Need I implement a LOCK in this queue, when writing a new element?

Thanks,
Daniel Koch

Comment: Why do not you try to use the UDP protocol. Packet losses are negligible.

Comment: Because I can lost the frame order. And I should make a listener to each expected channels (today IMGSvr doesn't know about channels, the number are coming in header).

Answer (score 1):

`send()` guarantees that writes are atomic, even though it does not guarantee that all the data passed to a single invocation will be accepted. Thus, the second thread has to wait until the first thread has appended its data to the send queue.

It is almost never a good idea to do this, as there are cases where data will be accepted only partially, after which the socket is unlocked and the second thread gets its chance -- in this case you will end up with an invalid output stream.

The approach with a dedicated writer and a queueing mechanism appears to be correct. You will need a lock to protect the queue, but the critical section required to append an item to a linked list is very short, so there shouldn't be any contention here.

Comment: Hi Simon, thanks for response. Must I pre-alloc memory to preserve time when frames are coming? I think it can be slow if each new frame call HeapAlloc to append struct in queue. What do you think?

Comment: That depends on how the allocator is implemented, which I don't know. I'd start with using OS allocation functions, and optimize if it turns out to be suboptimal.